# Python packages, simplest example not working. ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'simple_package'. Billionth time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to try really simple example of Python package.
It seems to be okay on IDE as it does not show any error or warnings, but when i execute the files, i get error which is really weird.

```
$ tree                                                
.
├── ReadMe.md
├── __init__.py
├── a.py
└── b.py


$ pwd         
$HOME/workspace/devops-essentials/languages/python/simple_package
```

a.py

```py
def bar():
    print("Hello, function 'bar' from module 'a' calling")
```

b.py

```py
from simple_package import a

def foo():
    print("Hello, function 'foo' from module 'b' calling")

a.bar()
```

```
$ python3 b.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ankitsinghrathi/Ankit/workspace/devops-essentials/languages/python/simple_package/b.py", line 1, in <module>
    from simple_package import a
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simple_package'


$ python3 simple_package/b.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ankitsinghrathi/Ankit/workspace/devops-essentials/languages/python/simple_package/b.py", line 1, in <module>
    from simple_package import a
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simple_package'
```

Comment: What directory are you calling `python3` in? Python will add that directory to the search path. So you need to be in the directory which contains `simple_package` (i.e. `$HOME/workspace/devops-essentials/languages/python`)

Comment: Thanks @PeterWood, i tried from the same path. But still the same error. I updated the question description.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: Honestly, I don't have that much patience. I would go there and leave. My problem is extremely simple and should have a short concise answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

```
$ tree $HOME/workspace/devops-essentials/languages/python/simple_package
├── ReadMe.md
├── __init__.py
├── a.py
└── b.py
```

then you'll need to be in `$HOME/workspace/devops-essentials/languages/python` and run

```
python -m simple_package.a
```

– using `-m` to execute the module will fix up your Python interpreter's path in a way that your imports work.

Comment: Amazing, you are the god @AKX, works like a charm. I wonder why this is not given anywhere in any python docs. I wanted to get this information for far too long. Gave up all hopes but then you came, the saviour :)

Comment: Another way around this would have been a `test_my_package.py` file in `python/` that does `import simple_package.a`, but yeah – this is documented in https://docs.python.org/3.9/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m

Comment: Why not `python simple_package/b.py`?

Comment: @PeterWood Because it doesn't fix up `sys.path` like this does.

Comment: But, it will only find module `simple_package.a` because the path has been fixed up by running `python` in the directory containing `simple_package`. How does `-m` do any further "fixing up"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change import statement in `b.py`

<s>from simple_package import a</s>  
import a

```py
import a

def foo():
    print("Hello, function 'foo' from module 'b' calling")

a.bar()
```

It will work perfectly fine, you can also use relative import like `from . import a` but when you will execute `b.py` it will throw RelativeImport error however when you use it outside the package it will work perfectly fine.